# Location of the android sdk has not been setup in the preferences

Tags: android, eclipse

I have read a lot of questions about this problem in this forum and elsewhere, but I cant find a solution that helps me! Despite that I have the SDK I get this message when I click on the AVD icon in Eclipse! And when i check in Windpos -> Preferences -> Android, the path to the SDK is there! But why doesn't it work!?

I have tried to download the latest version of ADT, but that is already installed. So what can I do to get rid of this message and start using the AVD? Help is preciated! Thanks! I'm using Windows 7.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide screen shots.

Comment: does your path have a space?the blurry part i mean

Comment: @Yazan No, that's just a name

Comment: ok, 3 possibilities i can think of, 1) is this path correct? if you copy/paste it to a window explorer it will be OK? 2) is this the root folder, some times the extract is tricky where you will find android-sdk inside that folder -so correct path might be.../android-sdk/android-sdk- 3) run eclipse as admin and rest the path

Comment: @Yazan I copy and paste the path and it works in window explorer. What do you mean by root folder? And how do I run eclipse as admin? Any other ideas? If I uninstall SDK and unzip it again, where should I put it to get it to work? Thanks!

Comment: @3D-kreativ by root i mean, if you compy/paste that path will you see the SDK fodlers? (platforms, tools,...) or you will see another folder? to run as admin, right click the eclipse icon and select run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

try to  add an '\' at the last of SDK Location path